# Word for prolong from the "front"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English that means to prolong from the "front"?

This search was inspired by the current situation with the pandemic. Some schools and colleges in the United States have called for their spring break* to begin at an earlier date (but end at the same date as the original spring break). I would like to say spring break was *prolonged* (to an earlier date), but I thought prolong would give the sense that the end of spring break was "delayed" or that the word would be too awkward to used in this context.

*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_break

Comment: “started early”

Comment: There isn't such a word, but it would be useful. How about *prelong*?

Comment: *Spring break was lengthened.*